# Unable to restore apps in Titanium Backup after marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, titanium-backup

I recently flashed my Note 4 (N910W8) to Marshmallow and rooted my device. I had taken backup of all my data using Titanium Backup while I was on Lollypop. Now after flashing my device with marshmallow, I am unable to restore my data as Titanium Backup is not able to detect / read the applications in the backup. It is only showing the older apps but not the latest ones. Could anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the latest version of TiBu? I remember there were several MM updates released to it.